# WHMCS - change the method used to check for domain availability

Tags: whmcs

First let me say that I don't have any experience with WHMCS, so this question might need to be corrected.

I am requested to change the way that WHMCS system checks for domain name availability.
They don't want to check from global network Nameservers but instead they want to use a custom web service to do the checking process.

Is it possible to be done?

It would be highly appreciated if you show me the steps that I need to take or show some hints to get started.

Comment: What WHMCS-version, since with 6.x this process has changed a lot?

Comment: @KimHoogenberg I don't know exactly what version does the client have. You can instruct me for the latest version.